# Graph Toolkit SPFx PeoplePicker (mgt-spfx,mgt-react) does it retieve/can be used with SharePoint groups?

Tags: reactjs, spfx, microsoft-graph-toolkit

Trying PeoplePicker in SPFx web-part from mgt-spfx,mgt-react ("@microsoft/mgt-react": "3.1.3", "@microsoft/mgt-spfx": "3.1.3") packages and do not see it retrieving SharePoint groups. Is it possible to configure or customize it so SharePoint groups are retrieved?

I have PeoplePicker with type={PersonType.any} working, but do not see SharePoint groups retrieved from the site collection (Team Site template, no M365 group) I am testing on (using online workbench).

Answer (score 1):

Because mgt-spfx uses the microsoft graph to fetch data it might be unable to retrieve sharepoint groups natively (I couldn't find a property that would do so at least).

You could fetch all SP security groups using this api endpoint: `https://{tenant}.sharepoint.com/sites/{sitename}/_api/web/sitegroups`

You might need to parse that data but you could then feed it to the mgt-peoplepicker in the `people={spGroupArr}` property.

An alternative would be to use the [sp-dev PeoplePicker](https://pnp.github.io/sp-dev-fx-controls-react/controls/PeoplePicker/) which has the option to fetch SharePoint groups: `principalTypes={[PrincipalType.SharePointGroup]}`

Hope this helps